# create a list of matrices in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new in python and Tensorflow, and I want to initialize **k** matrices(let say k=10) each one is 300X300, I wrote this line but I'm not sure is this the right way or not

```
 R = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(self.k, 300, 300)),name="R")
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right way, but be careful about that the variable is **NOT** initialized yet. It gets initialized when you actually run a initializer like:

```
R = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(10, 300, 300)),name="R")
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Seesion() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) # now R gets initialized
    r = sess.run(R) # load value of R as numpy array r
    # ... check r's value ...
```